# Bootstrap Modal Form Post/GET doesn't send field values

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a simple modal form :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content modal-lg">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Address Maintenance</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="maintainAddress" method='GET' action="test.php">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="addressID" class="col-sm-2 control-label input-sm">Address ID</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="addressID" placeholder="Address ID">
</div>
<label for="houseNo" class="col-sm-2 control-label input-sm">House No</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="houseNo" placeholder="House No">
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SAVE</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
</div>
</form>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

test.php is :

```
<?

$addressID=$_GET["addressID"];
$houseNo=$_GET["houseNo"];

echo  $addressID . " " .  $houseNo;


 ?>
```

test.php does get invoked on clicking 'SAVE' button but test.php is unable to receive any field values of addressID and houseNo. Error message is "

Notice: Undefined index: addressID in D:\proto\xampp\htdocs\scorecard\test.php on line 3
Notice: Undefined index: houseNo in D:\proto\xampp\htdocs\scorecard\test.php on line 4

I have tried changing GET to POST but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The form-elements should have the name-attribute set. So this:
`<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="houseNo" placeholder="House No">`

Should be changed to:
`<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="houseNo" name = "houseNo" placeholder="House No">`